# How was "GEOS" meant to be pronounced?

Tags: commodore, operating-system

[GEOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEOS_%288-bit_operating_system%29) was a hugely popular operating environment for 8-bit Commodore and Apple machines. It was developed and published by Berkeley Softworks, who eventually released [a 16-bit version for IBM-compatible PCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEOS_%2816-bit_operating_system%29).  Do we have any information on how the name of this system was intended to be pronounced?

I have heard *users* variously call it as follows:

- /ˈdʒiːˌɒs/ (JEE-ahss; last syllable rhymes with "boss")
- /ˈdʒiːˌoʊs/ (JEE-oce; last syllable rhymes with "dose")
- /ˈdʒiː ˈiː ˈoʊː ˈɛs/ (JEE-EE-OH-ESS; sounding out each letter individually)

What I'm more interested in is how the *creators* of GEOS pronounced the name of their system.  Does any contemporary user manual, advertisement, internal design document, or other "official" material indicate or give hints as to the pronunciation?  Are there any audio interviews with (former) Berkeley Softworks employees where we can hear the name "GEOS" spoken?

Comment: Heyoss in espagnol!

Comment: Well everyone over here simply pronounced it /geos/. Tells how simple Germans are:)

Comment: Hugely digressive, re: "hugely popular" do you have a good source for that? I read Commodore: The Final Years semi-recently and it dedicates a large amount of time to discussing GEOS, which was bundled with the C-1541 for at least a period, which left me wondering. My impression had always been that it was a gimicky sideshow, having limited adoption beyond Commodore's mug's eyeful-style giveaway. Might be because I'm from Europe where disk drives were never considered standard, of course, but otherwise it'd be cool if I could disprove my instinctive self.

Comment: @Tommy "I'm from Europe" is about as specific as saying "I'm human". Even by ignoring all the places in the east, which were kinda cut off until 1990 anyway, the West in itself was rather variant.. Britain, France, Germany and Italy none like the others. You might want to add detail. In addition 'disks not standard' might as well be time specific. In 1980, maybe, while in 1985, a C64 without a disk drive was a pretty uncommon sight. At least in Germany. And yes, GEOS did make quite some impact with users not switching for 16 bit. When GEOS came in 1986, people even PAYED 70 Marks to get it.

Comment: @Tommy The [May 1988 issue of COMPUTE!'s _Gazette_](https://archive.org/details/1988-05-computegazette/page/n5/mode/1up?view=theater) reported that nearly half of readers surveyed used GEOS. The magazine (and other Commodore-focused publications) dedicated many articles and even regular columns to GEOS. There were even several GEOS-themed magazines and disk magazines.

Comment: @MarkWilliams That was Digital Research's GEM, not GEOS.

Comment: @Raffzahn ["Disk drives were uncommon in Europe,"](https://dfarq.homeip.net/commodore-1541-disk-drive/), ["In the United States, the 1541 floppy disk drive was widespread. By contrast, in Europe, the C64 was often used with cassette tape drives "](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_64_peripherals#Floppy_disk_drives), ["Commodore Datasettes were actually the most common mass-storage devices for users of the more popular Commodore computers, such as the VIC-20 and C64. Especially in Europe, where disk drive prices were extremely high"](http://www.zimmers.net/cbmpics/dtapes.html).

Comment: ... and that's as many as will fit in one comment. Key points: (1) it is perfectly common to refer to 'Europe' as a single Commodore market; (2) it is similarly usual to note that tape drives were more popular than disk drives for use with Commodore computers in Europe.

Comment: @Tommy Serious, Europe as one market? From personal experience I can tell that there were for example huge differences in usage between the UK and Germany. In Germany the floppy drives were essential standard, not so much in the UK - this was as well visible with the packages Commodore sold. UK was more ofen than not some combination of C64 and game cartridge, while in Germany it was C64 and 1541. BTW: the Wiki article does not cite any sources for that claim, so id' rather stay sceptic about so blunt assumptions.

Comment: And yes, it might be common for US based commenters to see Europe as some unified body, being European should tell you that the continent is way more different than assumed from the outside. Doesn't it? But if you see it as one market, I guess you have checked german magazines of the late 80s and noted how  much room they gave to GEOS, have you?

Comment: @Raffzahn Only one of those links was to Wikipedia; all were found through an attempted open-question search. It's not like I typed "disk drives rate in Europe" or similar lopsided nonsense. I also specifically asked for primary sources that would disprove my initial unevidenced suspicions, but I can read enough German to get by so I'll check the Internet Archive. That all said, your reaction oversells your argument. I have a lot of difficulty believing that "in 1985, a C64 without a disk drive was a pretty uncommon sight".

Comment: @Tommy Sorry, but with a continuous line of links it's quite hard to see that there are multiply. my fault. IIRC there was even a GEOS magazine (for C64) by Markt & Technik. And yes, a C64 without a Disk was extreme uncommon in the second half of the 80s. In fact, I don't remember any C64 user one who hadn't gotten one by then. To make it clear, I'm not talking about prior to 1986 (when GEOS came). In the early days cassettes were quite common - but that changed quite fast, either by buying a floppy or switching or a different machine. It was as well the time of 16 bit, of Atari and Amiga.

Comment: @Tommy Which in fact brings another difference in European markets to mind. in the UK 8 bit stayed way longer relevant as in Germany. Amstrad as well as Sinclair (Amstrad) sold their machines well into the 90s - the PCW eventually all the way thru them, while the 8 bit market (read new machines) was essentially dead in Germany toward the end of the 1980s - well, except for an unexpected spike in sales in early 1990 to East Germany - and as well other eastern European countries. It was a quite diverse market back then. But differences are still there, look at usage for OOO or FF in DE vs GB.

Comment: Right; I also think Commodore Germany had a few profitable IBM clones well ahead of the Amstrads that are considered breakthrough devices in France and the UK?

Comment: @Tommy These ones? → [Commodore History Part 6 - The PC Compatibles - The 8-Bit Guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e63XWCW2ADY)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have mostly heard your first option, /ˈdʒiːˌɒs/, and analogously, also /ˈbiːˌɒs/ as the pronunciation of BeOS. My accent has /ɔ/ in this context, so /ˈdʒiːˌɔs/.

[This advert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kyhy1NxpVc), at 2:10, suggests that at least the marketing department also thought it should be pronounced that way.

Comment: That advertisement is from Commodore, not from Berkeley, though at the time the former had a deal with the latter to bundle GEOS with its computers, and so I suppose it's reasonable to expect that Berkeley had some involvement in the ad.

Comment: Never trust Marketing so to pronounce your beautiful product name the way you intended it!

Comment: As per the most famous example: its designer intended SCSI to be pronounced 'sexy'. So they not only found a different pronunciation, but a near opposite meaning.

Comment: @Tommy: That wasn't the designer. SCSI had been in use for some time, but Apple didn't like the usual pronunciation, so they instructed their salespeople to pronounce it "sexy".

Comment: Wikipedia credits it to Boucher, the principal architect, but without citing a source. So I can’t claim to have proven truth but if some misattribution has occurred, I promise I didn’t start it!

Comment: @Tommy: No problem. I used to live in Colorado Springs, where a number of the T10 folks lived. At least the ones I knew all thought it was a great joke when Apple started saying it (but that isn't a definitive statement that Boucher may not have said it first).

Answer (score 5):

I've just turned up an article on GEOS that includes an interview with Brian Dougherty, president of Berkeley Softworks.  The article [1], which appeared in *RUN*, describes how to say "GEOS" using what looks like the pronunciation key used by Merriam-Webster dictionaries:

> GEOS (pronounced jē ōs) stands for graphic environment operating system.

Rendered in the International Phonetic Alphabet, this would be /dʒiːoʊs/.

The quoted sentence isn't a direct quote from Dougherty, though it's highly likely that the article's author, *RUN* editor-in-chief Dennis Brisson, spoke with him directly and thereby learned his pronunciation of the name.

Of course, this contradicts [the answer given by OmarL](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/19638/6527), which also comes from a fairly proximate source (namely, a video by Commodore that presumably had close involvement from Berkeley).  It's possible that either Brisson or the Commodore marketing department got the pronunciation wrong.  It's also possible that Berkeley did not mandate, or at least did not enforce, a single official pronunciation, leading to its own employees speaking the name according to their own preferences.  (This is certainly the case with the name of the organization I work for—it's an acronym that can be pronounced in two different ways, and there's no consistency across or even within employees on which one is used.  In conversation people seem to just repeat the pronunciation of whoever said the name last.)

---

1. Brisson,  Dennis. [GEOS one year later](https://archive.org/details/run-magazine-43/page/n65/mode/2up). *RUN* 43:64–67, July 1987.